# jPlayer only works with 6 or less player instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, jplayer

I'm having an unusual issue with jPlayer. I have 10 instances of jPlayer on a page, only the first 6 work. The end 4 are unresponsive, as if the script hadn't even set events for the play/pause button.

I'd rather not have to change the player I'm using, as we have a deadline of this afternoon for the internal launch of a new website. This is a newly discovered issue. I have found several people asking this same question around Google, but not many. All of those threads appear to have no answers, just people leaving "me too" responses.

There are no Syntax errors, there are no errors in the JavaScript console. All instances, ids, classes etc. are correct and have been quadruple checked. I can think of zero reasons for why this might be happening, apart from a bug in jPlayer.

I can't really think of anything to try - so I can't say i've tried this, that and the other - to fix it.

If anybody has any ideas, or has encountered similar issues and has a resolution, please do not hesitate to respond.

Thanks in advance,
Caelan.

Comment: whats the selector you are passing for `cssSelectorAncestor`?

Comment: #cp_container_1 for the 1st player, #cp_container_2 for the 2nd player etc... each instance plays different audio files.

Comment: i have tried this in a fiddle and its working properly.

Comment: More than 6 jPlayer instances?

Comment: If so, can you post a link to the JSFiddle please?